# Function bound to resize event of wxpython widget gets called more than once while resizing

Tags: python, wxpython

I have made a small app with a GUI in python using the wxpython toolkit. It consists of a frame as the top window and 100 StaticText child widgets. I have bind their size events `(wx.EVT_SIZE)` to a `OnResize` function which changes their font according to the size of the StaticText widgets. (This helps to increase or decrease the size of the font of the widgets when I resize my frame window accordingly at runtime.)

Now the poblem is that the `OnResize` function gets called `4 times` every time I resize my frame. This considerably slowsdown the startup of my app (and also its resizing.) What I want is that the `OnResize` function must get called only once.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an alternative approach.

Keep a variable of the previously processed size. Then, in your size handler, only change the font size if the size of the widget actually changed since the last size event.

```
def OnResize(self, event):
    w, h = size = self.GetSize()
    if size != self.previous_size:
        # update font size
    self.previous_size = size
```

Comment: I think the 2nd line should be --> w, h = size = event.GetSize()